# how to rise the number of compiling permutations for GWT?

Tags: gwt

the gwt compiler in eclipse compiles only two permutations?
iam using the nextinterface framework for mobile devices which provides very good looking and easy to use UIs but its not more supported.
thats the reason why my app doesnt really work on mobile device.
is it possible to rise the number of permutations by hand?
and if its possible, how could i do it?

Comment: The number of permutations isn't limited to two by Eclipse. It depends on the number of supported languages ​​and browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Permutations are all, well, permutations of deferred-binding property values. By default with GWT 2.4, you'll have 6 `user.agent` value (`gecko1_8`, `safari`, `ie6`, `ie8`, `ie9` and `opera`) and 1 default `locale` (`default`). That makes 6 permutations. If you add a locale, you'll have 12 permutations, etc.

I don't know the *nextinterface frameworl* but it may *artificially* limit (i.e. without your consent/knowledge) the number of permutations by setting the `user.agent` property to a limitted set of values (e.g. `<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari, gecko1_8" />` to only support Firefox and Safari/Chrome).

Anyway, you don't want to "rise the number of permutations [by hand]", you possibly want to support more user agents, more locales, more generally more runtime environments. That generally implies having more permutations, but that's definitely not a *goal* to persue (quite the contrary actually: if we could have a single code working everywhere –a single permutation, i18n put aside–, that'd be much better!)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like NEXT mobile only does a special permutation for safari, then all other browsers use the other permutation.  Any UI issues you see with other mobile platforms should probably be taken up with the framework creator (or use a different framework).

Also, looking at their google groups, it looks like NEXT mobile framework is dead:

http://groups.google.com/group/nextinterfaces/browse_thread/thread/020b5b860b8dc784#

> Thanks for using NEXTinterfaces, unfortunately I would recommend using viable alternative as NEXT is no longer supported.